# Postgresql9.6 Sharding

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sharding, database-administration

I have a database topology as in the picture attached below and postgresql9.6 is installed in all the machines. It is master-slave architecture with sharding. I have successfully configured master-slave replication and automatic failover using repmgr/repmgrd. But i am confused on how to achieve sharding in this scenario. I have tried citus extension, but for the table structure i have citus does not support sharding, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660398/posrgresql-sharding-with-citus-extension-not-working). Can anyone suggest me how can i achieve sharding in this scenario.

Database topology:

[image]